# What is the best way to stop multiple form submissions using PHP?

Tags: php

I wanted to know what is the best way to stop multiple form submissions using PHP, can you please give an example.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side you can simply disable the form button after its clicked. However, this provides a very basic level of security.

Your next step would be to prevent it via PHP. In which case, it is best to have a hidden field within your form which consists of a *unique* and identifiable token. In order to perform your check, you will have to keep a list of tokens that have been used in the past and check if it has been submitted before.

Comment: I've always wondered about reenabling the button. Should we use `setTimeout()` (or similar) to reenable it if the user presses 'stop'. Is there an `onabort` for that is fired when the users aborts the form  submission? Anyway, +1 :)

Comment: Well the whole purpose of it is to thwart multiple submissions. If you're providing a means to cancel a submission than re-enabling `submit` seems like a must from a UI point of view. Instead of `setTimeout()`, you could simply fire an event when the abort has been clicked.

Comment: What event is fired when the user aborts the submission though?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//do stuff with the form input
//do not display anything
header('Location: ready.php');

?>
```

eaysiest and fastest way is to redirect the user to another page so if he relodes after redirection no input will be sent a second time.

You can use $_SESSION to store the users state, i.e. if he already sent the form or not.